# Android API is missing on customized Android OS

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm trying to read and write files on external memory card of Android device.
I used below code and you can refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal for more detail.

```
public String getExternalPath(){

    int ver = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    File[] externalRoots = null;
    if(ver <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){          
        externalRoots = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(getBaseContext(), null);
    } else {
        externalRoots = getExternalFilesDirs(null);   
    }   

    File externalRoot = null;
    if(externalRoots.length > 1){
        externalRoot = externalRoots[1];
    } else {
        externalRoot = externalRoots[0];
    }       
    if(externalRoot != null){
        return externalRoot.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, it works properly on some devices, not all. For example, with Asus devices, LG or Samsung Devices, reading and writing files on external memory card (Removable) works very well, but on Chinese devices such as Lenovo, Aquaris, it can't.

Could you help me explain why this problem happens? or give me some official document talking about differences on OEM customized Android OS.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for post here but have you able to count hair? I have same requirement can you please help me to calculate hair using OpenCv or others.